# Unable to Access Element in a Perl Hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, array-splice

I have a hash, populated with following test data:

```
my %non_root_files = ('views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/sample_sgdc_file_contents_1.sgdc' => 1, 
                  'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/sample_sgdc_file_contents.sgdc' => 1,
                  'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_2.sgdc' => 1,
                  'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_4.sgdc' => 1,
                  'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_5.sgdc' => 1,
                  'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_6.sgdc' => 1);
```

In another array, I have the following data:

```
my @files = ('views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/sample_sgdc_file_contents.sgdc', 
             'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_2.sgdc',
             'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/sample_sgdc_file_contents_1.sgdc',
             'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_5.sgdc',
             'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/test_7.sgdc',
             'views/SPYGLASS_HOME/bin/sample_sgdc_file_contents_2.sgdc');
```

what I need to do is to check if each entry in the array is present in the hash, and delete from the original array, so I do it as follows:

```
sub deleteDuplicate{

    $originalList_ref = shift;
    my $index = 0;
    foreach my $element (@{$originalList_ref})
    {
       if(exists $non_root_files{$element})
       {
          splice(@{$originalList_ref}, $index, 1);
       }
       $index++;
    }
}
```

However, for some entries which are actually present in the hash, the lookup with exists is failing. The element is there in the hash, but if condition is returning false. Can anyone please explain the reason for this and how to correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: The lookup is not failing if the key exists in the hash. I suggest adding some print statements so you can actually see what's going on and debug your code. I will suspect the real problem is you're modifying your array as you iterate through it and your `$index` is then no longer correct.

Comment: What is @files for? I don't see it used in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brian's comment is correct; you want:

```
   if(exists $non_root_files{$element})
   {
      splice(@{$originalList_ref}, $index, 1);
   }
   else
   {
      $index++;
   }
```

(If you delete an entry in the array, the next entry will move back to that same index).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding `foreach` loops in [perldoc perlsyn](https://metacpan.org/module/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops):

> If any part of LIST is an array, foreach will get very confused if you
>   add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with splice.
>   So don't do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have not come across that before. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to do this:

```
sub deleteDuplicate {
    $original_ref = shift;
    $originalList_ref = [ grep { ! exists $non_root_files{$_} } @$originalList_ref ];
}
```